# Send Notification to IOS app after payment transaction happpened through web client

Tags: php, ios, paypal

I am creating a website as well as ios App. I implemented paypal and creadit card payment with it. Current scenario is when user open ios app and came at the point to purchase something. He'll select option either paypal or credit card. On selection of any option,respective window  will open in web browser. After that user will input his credential for paypal/credit card. It will process input and generate some output like success response, failure response.
My problem is how to show or send that response message to ios app from web browser.

Push notification can be used for this but don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the transaction result in the database (on the web server) and create a simple API that will enable your app to make a call to the web server, and get a response like "paid / not paid"

Comment: yes we can do like this. But when to call this API through app. Paypal page will get opened in the browser and suddenly client close the browser then? How to get it notify to the app that at this time it need to make API call for payment status.

Comment: you probably need to check it anyway when user try to access paid content, so if you dont see that user have paid, send API request, if it get back negative open paypal window

Comment: current scenario is we allow user to enter information and if he makes the payment then only user can submit his details otherwise submit button will be disable.